# How to create sitecore item version without workflow?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-workflow

I came across business requirement in Sitecore where for few items we don't need to attached workflow but we want to create new version when we lock edit the item.

I cant apply below setting as it will impact all the items and my workflow will not useful.

```xml
<setting name="RequireLockBeforeEditing" value="true"/>
```

I also gone through [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988432/sitecore-users-edit-item-creates-new-version) and it has given below solution but not sure on which event it should be.

```cs
public Item StartEditing(Item item)
{
  Error.AssertObject((object) item, "item");
  if (!Settings.RequireLockBeforeEditing || Context.User.IsAdministrator)
    return item;
  if (this._context.IsAdministrator || StandardValuesManager.IsStandardValuesHolder(item) || !this.HasWorkflow(item) && !this.HasDefaultWorkflow(item) || !this.IsApproved(item))
    return this.Lock(item);
  Item obj = item.Versions.AddVersion();
  if (obj != null)
    return this.Lock(obj);
  else
    return (Item) null;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to force the new version of an item for all editors when they start editing an item? You can have a look at "item:locked" event, but is it not enough to use `ribbon > Versions > Add` button?

Comment: Yes, we want to force the new version of an item for all editors when they start editing an item. No we cant use ribbon option as editors are not familiar with it. I will create version on item:locked event. I've also checked show.config there I have seen item:edit command can we leverage that?

Comment: I don't think `item:edit` command is called everywhere, e.g. not sure about experience editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

Patch item:saved event:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <events>
      <event name="item:saved">
        <handler type="PersonalizationDemo.Data.Items.ItemEventHandler, PersonalizationDemo" method="OnItemSaved"/>
      </event>
    </events>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Implement class of custom event handler:

```
namespace PersonalizationDemo.Data.Items
{
    using Sitecore.Data.Items;
    using Sitecore.Events;
    using System;

    public class ItemEventHandler
    {
        protected void OnItemSaved(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            if (args == null) { return; }

            var sitecoreEventArgs = args as SitecoreEventArgs;
            if (sitecoreEventArgs == null) { return; }

            if (sitecoreEventArgs.Parameters.Length < 2) { return; }

            var item = sitecoreEventArgs.Parameters[0] as Item;
            if (item == null) { return; }

            if (!this.ShouldItemBeProcessed(item)) { return; }

            var itemChanges = sitecoreEventArgs.Parameters[1] as ItemChanges;
            if (itemChanges == null) { return; }

            if (itemChanges.FieldChanges.Contains(Sitecore.FieldIDs.Lock))
            {
                var fieldChange = itemChanges.FieldChanges[Sitecore.FieldIDs.Lock];
                if (fieldChange.Value == "<r />") { return; }

                this.CreateNewVersion(item);
            }
        }

        protected bool ShouldItemBeProcessed(Item item)
        {
            // TODO implement necessary check
            return true;
        }

        protected void CreateNewVersion(Item item)
        {
            var newItem = item.Versions.AddVersion();

            newItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
            // update necessary field if you need that
            newItem.Editing.EndEdit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is on item saved. I want to create an version as an when user click on lock & edit

Comment: Lock & Edit also updates item. `item:saved` event is most probably called. It looks like a good alternative to `item:locked` event.

Comment: @SunilAher this code works exactly when you click 'Edit' button. Under the hood when you click 'Edit' button Sitecore changes the value of 'Lock' field of the item and also save it. And code above checks changes within Sitecore.FieldIDs.Lock field of the item, and if it was changed it creates a new version. Just try, you will see it works.

Comment: @AlekseyShevchenko Thanks for detailed information. yes, saved event gets called when I clicked on edit&lock. Your solution gives me what exactly I want... :) Cheers.